# What testing framework is meant for writing typescript unit tests that will execute in the browser?

Tags: typescript

I'm pretty new to typescript but I'm trying to write unit tests for my production code. I chose Jasmine, but I keep butting heads with it. My production code will actually run in the browser, but I think Jasmine assumes that my production code will run in node. What testing frameworks assume that they are running in the browser, or at least have the option of running in the browser?

I should explain that I don't really need to use the DOM.  All my unit tests are really simple and straightforward like testing a function that looks like this:

```
function add(first, second) {...}
```

That said, I do need access to global variables like window.  My code isn't assuming that there's anything in `window`, but it does want to set variables on it and retrieve them.

Answer (score 1):

Any testing framework will run inside a node environment, which is your terminal's environment. If you wanted to strictly run inside a browser, you would need to look at an end-to-end testing framework like Cypress.

A simpler and more lightweight alternative is to use [Jest](https://jestjs.io/)! It is pretty popular for frontend testing and uses JSDOM as a backend as default, which enables most of the Web's APIs in Node, so you could access window properties normally. Using `jest.mock` you should be able to easily mock any window methods, such as `window.location.push()`.

If you find any issues with accessing these global variables, I found these resources:

- [Official docs: Mocking methods which are not implemented in JSDOM](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom)
- [Mocking in Jest](https://medium.com/@ian.mundy/mocking-in-jest-4e5cc6233a7c)
- [Jest: mock window.location methods](https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2018/11/17/mock-window-location/)

Comment: I have no problem running my mocha + chai tests in a browser. It's a built-in feature and even generates a HTML test report.  I assume the same exists in Jest.

Comment: You might be right about Jest though: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/139

Comment: I personally prefer using mocha for my Node projects, as test times for Typescript are way faster than Jest's. But for frontend, Jest seems more suitable, specially considering its community traction over the years: https://2019.stateofjs.com/testing/